# editing chrome extensions problem with corrupted files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, google-chrome-extension

I have been recently working on a project to make a simple download renamer and it worked. However, i just need to append its code to my download manager extension (Ant download manager). When i try to change the background script edge gives error : 'extension might be corrupted' and a repair option with no option to let it work. I tried removing the update_url and replacing it with any other in the manifest.json (editing other files than the background script doesn't elect the error) but still gave the same error when i edited background script.

NOTE: when i load the unpacked source code of the extension, it doesn't function properly.

I thought of changing the path of native host in json manifest to a custom C++ host that would receive the stdin and then send the modified data as stdout to the original native host but this would be a lengthy solution and encounter a lot of errors.

Comment: => Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080848/edited-chrome-extension-chrome-thinks-it-is-malware Else check this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757849/chrome-extension-disabled-this-extension-may-have-been-corrupted-chrome-63-0-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` field in the `manifest.json` belongs to a verified extension and browsers check installation against that in their database against possible corruption by any means.

your edit will be seen as corruption even if you change the update URL because of this `id`.

- make a copy of the extension folder. find it in browser's own extensions folder. check internet for where that location be.
- remove extension from browser
- now edit codes for your needs
- edit `manifest.json` and remove app specific things like this `id`. some may have hash values etc.
- enable developer mode in the browser and install from the folder you used. by "install" I mean browser use that folder. it will not copy content into browser's extensions folder. so keep it in somewhere like `~/myextensions`, or `c:\workspace\myextensions`

---

also check for a `_metadata` folder and the content inside. there might be related identifiers you need to remove in there.

Comment: I tried coping source code then loading it unpacked but it didn't work as expected the extension didn't recognize the instance of the native host .I think since the program has two options (either standard or premium user ), it would be very hard to load a third party extension to work with it.However I will give it a try and tell you what happened

Comment: There is no metadata file and no `id` or hash is apparent in the sourcecode

Comment: my answer was based on my previous work on another extension. I now tried on the extension you named here. its version is 0.4.30 and I used 2.5.1 portable version of the program. Edge removes `_metadata` folder when it loads the extension. I tried to change the formatting of the file, and seems it is still working. Edge 96.0.1054.62. check your versions and check if you dont have bug if your edits @mohamed

Comment: i figured out the problem i downloaded the source code using CRX extenssion and for some reason the code didn't work but when I copy and paste original files (along with my added modifications) it works just fine. Thanks for trying the problem by yourself